# Is there any solution except timeline for small animation in java fx?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, scenebuilder

I am a beginner in javafx.
I need to use small animations so much . Is there any way to create small animation except timeline ?
Thank's

Comment: What kind of animation are you looking forward to ?

Comment: Please see this page :http://tympanus.net/Development/ProgressButtonStyles/    I want to create the first button for example. I want to active the progress bar for mouse_pressed handle . and then I want to SUBMIT label go up from the middle of button.and mark image go up from bottom of the button and then SUBMIT label go down from the top of button again!! I don't know any way except timeline class and override handle method more and more !!!

Comment: I used translateY() method but it was high speed !!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the three options for animation in JavaFX are:

1. `Transition` [javadoc](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/animation/Transition.html), [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/animations/basics.htm#CJAJJAGI) (high-level)
2. `Timeline` [javadoc](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/animation/Timeline.html), [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/animations/basics.htm#CJAFADFJ) (intermediate-level)
3. `AnimationTimer` [javadoc](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/animation/AnimationTimer.html), [tutorial](http://blog.netopyr.com/2012/06/14/using-the-javafx-animationtimer/) (low-level)

In general when picking an animation API to use for your application, start at the highest level and see if there is a [Transition](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/animation/Transition.html) type which fits your requirements.  If not, consider subclassing Transition.  If there is no matching Transition and subclassing Transition isn't really what you want to do, then use a [Timeline](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/animation/Timeline.html) for most other tasks.  If all you want to do is intercept every rendering pulse of the application and take some action based on that, then you can use the [AnimationTimer](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/animation/AnimationTimer.html).